# Uncaught Runtime Exception : Unable to load ZF2 Run `php composer.phar install`

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php

When I try to run my project in localhost I am getting the above error.

The thing is I already installed the composer. In terminal I get the confirmation saying

> Composer (version 1.4.2) successfully installed to: /home/martin/composer.phar
>   Use it; php composer.phar

Even I tried the command `composer` It is showing the Composer things.

What should I do to get rid of the error `Fatal error : Uncaught Runtime Exception ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this issue you need to change php files.

***1.php.ini***

You can add the Zend Framework’s library path to the PHP include_path.

You can find include_path in php.ini.

**Example #1 Unix include_path**

```
include_path=".:/php/includes"<br>
```

**Example #2 Windows include_path**

```
include_path=".;c:\php\includes"
```

***2.httpd.conf***

You should set an environment path named ‘ZF2_PATH’ in httpd.conf (or equivalent). i.e. SetEnv ZF2_PATH /var/ZF2 running Linux.

Comment: what i have is `;UNIX:"\path1:\path2";include_path = ".:usr/share/php"` isnt this enough?

Comment: You need to add **Zend framework's library path** for that,

add a colon to the end, and then add the path after that. For example, you could change this:

**':/usr/local/zendsvr6/share/ZendFramework2/library'**

Comment: how can i check if i have this `ZendFramework2` in terminal? i mean i need to see the correct path

Comment: You may check in 

**/usr/share/zend/**,**/usr/share/php/**, or **/usr/local/zend/**